# What is `_.unDefined`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What exactly is `_.unDefined`? Is it built into JS or part of jQuery? It's a hard thing to Google for.

Comment: In what context? I've never seen such a construct.

Comment: `_`is probably underscore or other library using `_`.... And it probably just check if the variable is undefined.... Just check what library you are loading.

Comment: I saw it in a presentation. @Brennan pointed me in the right direction and I figured it out. It's from this http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a part of Javascript, it comes from a library kind of like lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#isUndefined

Comment: That's `_.isUndefined`. The OP is looking for `_.unDefined`

Comment: @Ninsly, I am aware, that's why I said it's from a library LIKE lodash, not that it is from lodash

Comment: @Brennan Thanks saw it in a presentation - with you hint i am pretty sure it was from http://underscorejs.org/ in the presentation. Doesn't help that I was so tired I didn't the function name down right.